# Blog CMS Some questions

Tags: php, mysql, content-management-system, blogs

I am coding my own Blog cms. In which i wants to code the following features.

> Public Area:

1.Navigation Bar.

2.Posts on the index page which includes. Small post image then post title and post content of about 200 characters. Then a Read more button that will take the user to full post page.

> Admin Area:

1.Posts CRUD (Create Read Update Delete).

2.General Information CRUD like Title Meta Keyowords and some other stuff.

> What i can do from the above is:

1.I can grab the post content etc from the database .

1. I can create the post CRUD.

The things i need help about are:
How i can create the full post page means when user clicks on Read More button or post title it will take the user to full post page. I don't know how this whole things works. 
Can you please explain how i can create this , how i will manage the database for this. It seems simple but i dont have any idea how i can do it.
If possible any example simple cms that has this feature (Not wordpress and others). Any tutorials on how to do this ?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks a lot 
Jasminder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the term "CRUD" = Create, Read, Update, Delete. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete

> How i can create the full post page means when user clicks on Read
>   More button or post title it will take the user to full post page. I
>   don't know how this whole things works.

It is actually quite simple. You would need to use $_GET to get some value that would associate to a certain post, for example if you have a table like:

> id title body created

It would make sense to associate the post with id.  Then you would have a file, let's call it "read.php"
 In that file you need to get the $_GET value and then query for the post the id is associated with:

Pseudo:

```
    <?php

    if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
     $id = $_GET['id']; //Make sure the value is of integer before continuing

     $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, body, created FROM posts WHERE id = $id");

     $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

     //present the result


echo "<h1>" . $row['title'] . "</h1>";
echo "<div>" . $row['body'] . "</div>";

//etc..

    }
```

Remember to protect against with XSS. http://shiflett.org/articles/cross-site-scripting

Comment: Awesome man. I did it :D. 
I will be posting here if any further queries. Thanks a lot .

Comment: No problem, if you are happy with the answer of this question, please mark my answer as "accepted".